# Jquery accordion with repeater, row details are not visible when activating row

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to use the jquery accordion with a repeater. I used the sample directly from the jquery documentation. When I click on the section links, the details open and expand, but you can't see any of the text. The html output looks right to me, not sure where this is going wrong.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <asp:Repeater ID="respondToExceptionsList" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
        <div>
            sdfffffffffffffff
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

This is the html output.

```
<DIV id=accordion class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role=tablist jQuery1315324170464="2">
    <H3 aria-expanded=true class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role=tab tabIndex=0 jQuery1315324170464="3">
    <SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" jQuery1315324170464="13"></SPAN><A tabIndex=-1 href="#">Section 1</A></H3>
    <DIV style="HEIGHT: 19px" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role=tabpanel>sdfffffffffffffff </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Do you only have on element in you repeater?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code you provided. It could be an interaction with the surrounding elements and CSS. Can you post the full code on jsfiddle.net or directly here if it's small enough?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I was afraid it might be something else interfering. Our application is pretty heavy, so I'm just going to skip trying to debug all of that and do a simple row expand / collapse.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the accordion height being set to zero.  I am having the same issue using the accordion in an html repeater generated using [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/). To fix the problem, the accordion must be refreshed after the data is loaded. I found the answer in the jquery forums [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-height-set-to-zero-issue).